# How do i disable or limit Postgres Replication creating causing too many WAL files generated?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, performance, write-ahead-logging, postgresql-performance

On AWS RDS PostgreSQL 10.7,
I turned on logical replication for a one specific table
.

on publisher:

```
CREATE PUBLICATION mypublication FOR TABLE <mytable>;
```

on subscriber:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION mysub
         CONNECTION 'host=... port=... user=foo dbname=foodb'
        PUBLICATION mypublication;
```

However, this led to some interesting errors where the WAL files generated ate up > 100 times the size of the table I replicated and I had to shut it down.
I started following the AWS guiding for troubleshooting this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/diskfull-error-rds-postgresql/

on AWS RDS, this was indicated by `TransactionLogsDiskUsage` metric.

It seems almost like it's trying to generate WAL files for any changes to the DB instead of just that table.
This was indicated by `OldestReplicationSlotLag` increasing when there are write to any tables instead of the specified table.

I tried looking at postgres error logs on RDS but still can't really understand the cause. Is there way to limit the WAL files created by logical replication?

Comment: You mean that the `pg_wal` directory is growing in size, right? Look at the log file of the standby server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database generates WAL for the entire database instance.  It is the logical sender's job to sort them out to restrict and construct what gets sent.  I don't think there is a way to get the logical sender to work ahead.  You should look at why it is falling behind, not why there is a lot of WAL.